# Get text including line breaks from uploaded pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am currently working on a small website, on which it should be possible to upload a .pdf file. For the websites functionality, I need to read the text from the pdf into a variable, including the line breaks. So for example if the text in the pdf is:

```
Hello World
How are you today?
```

Then the text in the variable should be "Hello World\nHow are you today?".

I have tried several things, but none of these worked for me.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="file" accept=".pdf">
```

I have tried the following code in my app.js:

```
function readPdf(){
    const file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    var output = "";
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        output += reader.result;
    }, false);

    if (file) {
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
    return output;
}
```

But this is only giving me a hieroglyphic string.

Has anyone ever tried something like this and could tell me the way how it is done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Do you mean https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-to-text as simple CLI pdftotext or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, this is way more complicated than I expected, so lets see. Anyways, thanks for your help!